# how to remove space before List of Figures

Tags: spacing

How can I remove the space before the List Of Figures in List of Figures page.
I am using report class.

Thank you

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Do you mean the space before the title, right?

Comment: Please add a MWE (minimal working example) for know what class are you using, the packages and a sample of code. I think you're using the book class or another similar which by default open each chapter or similar division in the right page. If you avoid this in the `documentclass` options then perhaps you can solve yuour issue.

Answer (score 6):

The macro responsible for the placement of the LoF's title is `\@makeschapterhead`, which is the same involved when printing starred chapters (`\chapter*`).

So, one way to achieve what you want is to patch `\@makeschapterhead` before `\listoffigures` so to remove the spacing and patch it back to restore the original behavior later.

The code to do this, is the following (requires `etoolbox`):

```
\let\oldlistoffigures\listoffigures
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{%
  \patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\relax}{}{}%
  \oldlistoffigures%
  \patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\relax}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}%
}  
\makeatother
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\let\oldlistoffigures\listoffigures
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{%
  \patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\relax}{}{}%
  \oldlistoffigures%
  \patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\relax}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}%
}  
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\chapter*{Test}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]